# AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encryption java to php with IV values in array in Java - how to convert the code from Java to PHP?

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

I need to be able to encrypt and decrypt in php. I have the Sample Java code which needs to be converted to Java, and I have given below. As much as I have searched, I am not able to find a single instance where an iv value is given as an array(I think). Please see Java code below

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.net.URL; 
import java.net.URLEncoder; 
import java.net.URLDecoder; 

public class SecurityTest {

private static byte[] sharedkey = "A1234&ABCDE/98745#000078".getBytes();

private static byte[] sharedvector = {8, 7, 5, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 18, 17, 15, 16, 14, 11, 12, 13};

private static String decyptString ;
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        SecurityTest test = new SecurityTest();
        System.out.println("Before assignment :"+sharedkey);
        System.out.println("IV Value is :"+sharedvector);

            sharedkey = "A1234&ABCDE/98745#000078".getBytes();
            System.out.println("API Doc Key :"+sharedkey);
            decyptString = "f5s0RMaYtr4WQseVR9E%2F3A%3D%3D";

        String text = "Hello World";
        System.out.println("This is a hello world encryption effort");
        test.EncryptButton("Hello World");

        test.DecryptButton(decyptString);

    }

private void EncryptButton(String actualTxt){
        try{
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(sharedkey, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(sharedvector));
        byte[] encrypted = c.doFinal(actualTxt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String strret = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
        strret = strret.replace("\n", "");
        System.out.println("Encoded String :"+strret);
        System.out.println("URL Encoded :"+URLEncoder.encode(strret,"UTF-8"));
        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
private void DecryptButton(String encryptedString){
    try{

        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(sharedkey, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(sharedvector));
        // byte[] decrypted = c.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(URLDecoder.decode(encryptedString,"UTF-8")));
        byte[] decrypted = c.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(URLDecoder.decode(encryptedString,"UTF-8")));
        System.out.println(new String(decrypted, "UTF-8"));
        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> The Java output is
> This is a hello world encryption effort
>
> Encoded String :f5s0RMaYtr4WQseVR9E/3A==
>
> URL Encoded :f5s0RMaYtr4WQseVR9E%2F3A%3D%3D

I have seen samples where encryption in PHP is done using openssl, but the IV values are not as what is given here, like an array. The IV values are in the byte array sharedvector.
This is the part where I need help in writing the equivalent in PHP

> private static byte[] sharedvector = {8, 7, 5, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 18, 17, 15, 16, 14, 11, 12, 13};

How do I write this IV in PHP ?

The PHP Code that I have is listed below:

```
$method = "AES-256-CBC";
$plaintext="Hello World";
$key="A1234&ABCDE/98745#000078";
    $sharedvector =  "\x08\x07\x05\x06\x04\x01\x02\x03\x12\x11\x0f\x10\x0e\x0b\x0c\x0d";
    $sharedvectorHex = unpack('H*', $sharedvector);

$encrypted = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $sharedvectorHex[1]));
echo "encrypted is ".$encrypted;
```

I am getting the following error.

> openssl_encrypt(): IV passed is 32 bytes long which is longer than the 16 expected by selected cipher, truncating

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe this answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62141866/edit. It's for aes gcm but will show you how to work with the init vector

Comment: Do you trying searching in the documentation? The docs for [openssl_decrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php) seem to be pretty clear where the IV goes.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelFehr, my problem is the java code that I have has "sharedvector" as an array, however the link that you have provided has code that is generated through the method random.nextbytes(). I am not able to figure out how to do this in PHP.

Comment: Thanks @PresidentJamesK.Polk the link and the documentation that you have given clearly says where the iv has to go, but my problem is that how do I convert the iv that is in the java code to php? Once I figure out the conversion I can use the method in the documentation.

Comment: Updated the question including suggestion from Michael in the PHP code. Still having trouble.

Comment: @Ravi: please see my second answer, that should work now for you

Comment: @MichaelFehr, Thanks for the answer. I should be able to get the same output of encrypted strings in both Java and PHP. In Java for "Hello World" the output I get is f5s0RMaYtr4WQseVR9E/3A==, which has been verified by the party providing the service. In PHP, I should be able to get the same output. The output that we are getting is Pi1TfbyAcEOxvfzFMItPLA==. I am not sure, what I am missing. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: @Ravi: please see my edited answer with a full working solution

Comment: @MichaelFehr, your solution works. Thanks so much. You are the best !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building an byte array as written in your code uses **decimal** values that got converted to a **hex**string representation as follows:

```
byte[] sharedvector = {8, 7, 5, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 18, 17, 15, 16, 14, 11, 12, 13};
System.out.println("\nsharedvector (Java): " + bytesToHex(sharedvector));
// byte array to hexstring method:
private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }
```

Result:

```
sharedvector (Java): 080705060401020312110f100e0b0c0d
```

Same workflow in PHP - please keep in mind that the decimal values in Java are converted to hex values manually:

```
$sharedvector =  "\x08\x07\x05\x06\x04\x01\x02\x03\x12\x11\x0f\x10\x0e\x0b\x0c\x0d";
$sharedvectorHex = unpack('H*', $sharedvector);
echo "sharedvector (PHP): " . $sharedvectorHex[1];
```

Result:

```
sharedvector (PHP) : 080705060401020312110f100e0b0c0d
```

Of course you can convert the decimal values to hexvalues with a PHP-function but I'm to lazy to implement this for a static value of 16 bytes :-)

```
Function in PHP:
dechex ( int $number ) : string
```

**Edit - solution with PHP full working sample:**

This answer follows the simple rule "never trust anything" (I'm joking) :-). On Java side you are using a string as source for the encryption key
that is encoded to a byte array via ".getBytes()". Printing out the length of the key will present us "**24**" and that's the key length for an
**AES-CBC-192** encryption:

```
System.out.println("sharedKey length: " + sharedkey.length);
sharedKey length: 24
```

With that given I changed your PHP-code to "**AES-192-CBC**" and you can use the $sharedvector directly as it is. The encrypted string is the same for Java and PHP: `f5s0RMaYtr4WQseVR9E/3A==`. Just to be sure everything is working I added the decryption part in PHP as well.

```
<?php
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62449449/aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-encryption-java-to-php-with-iv-values-in-array-in-java-ho/62454297#62454297
$method = "AES-192-CBC";
$plaintext = "Hello World";
$key = "A1234&ABCDE/98745#000078";
$sharedvector =  "\x08\x07\x05\x06\x04\x01\x02\x03\x12\x11\x0f\x10\x0e\x0b\x0c\x0d";
$encrypted = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $sharedvector));
echo "encrypted is " . $encrypted . "<br>";
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted), $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $sharedvector);
echo  "decrypted is " . $decrypted;
/* output
encrypted is f5s0RMaYtr4WQseVR9E/3A==
decrypted is Hello World
*/
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael Fehr I will check this one out.

Comment: Thank you @Michael Fehr for the answer. I have added more details to the question. I did try your suggestion, and I have posted the code that I have tried. I do not seem to get why it is not working. Can you please check and let me know what I am missing? Thanks so much !

Comment: Thanks so much for your support. This is the solution. You are the best !!

Answer (score 2):

I misunderstood what the data is for, sorry.

Using a function like

```
function hexToStr($hex){
    // Remove spaces if the hex string has spaces
    $hex = str_replace(' ', '', $hex);
    return hex2bin($hex);
}
```

that is called in your PHP-code:

```
$method = "AES-256-CBC";
$plaintext = "Hello World";
$key = "A1234&ABCDE/98745#000078";
$sharedvector = "8 7 5 6 4 1 2 3 18 17 15 16 14 11 12 13";
$iv = hexToStr($sharedvector);
$encrypted = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
echo "encrypted is " . $encrypted;
```

results in a working encryption:

```
encrypted is Pi1TfbyAcEOxvfzFMItPLA==
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael
The Java output for encyrpting "Hello World" is f5s0RMaYtr4WQseVR9E/3A==  
This has been verified and confirmed by the service provider. 
With PHP for "Hello World", we should be able to get the output f5s0RMaYtr4WQseVR9E/3A==. 
The one with your code gets an output of Pi1TfbyAcEOxvfzFMItPLA==
I am able to successfully encrypt but need to be able to get the same encryption as the Java code. Please check and let me know what I should do differntly to get the same output as Java. 

Thanks.